# Find and Replace RegEx question

Tags: c#, regex, replace, find, wildcard

I am starting to get a grip on RegEx thanks to all the great help here on SO with my other questions.  But I am still suck on this one:

My code is:

```
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fDialog.FileName.ToString());
   string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
   reader.Close();
```

I am reading in a text file and I want to search for this text and change it (the X and Y value always follow each other in my text file):

**X17.8Y-1.**

But this text can also be **X16.1Y2.3** (the values will always be different after X and Y)

I want to change it to this

**X17.8Y-1.G54**
or
**X(value)Y(value)G54**

My RegEx statement follows but it is not working.

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"(X(?:\d*\.)?\d+)*(Y(?:\d*\.)?\d+)", "$1$2G54");
```

Can someone please modify it for me so it works and will search for X(wildcard) Y(Wildcard) and replace it with X(value)Y(value)G54?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression you need is:

```
X[-\d.]+Y[-\d.]+
```

Here is how to use it in C#:

```
string content = "foo X17.8Y-1. bar";
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"X[-\d.]+Y[-\d.]+", "$0G54");
Console.WriteLine(content);
```

Output:

```
foo X17.8Y-1.G54 bar
```

Comment: This now also matches strings like `"X-17--2..3.-Y-...1."`, which I don't think he wants.  His original regex in his question specifically filters out non-numeric expressions (it only accepts numbers like .5 or 2.3 or 44).  Wouldn't this introduce false positives?

Comment: Thanks for the change.  Your right, it is a lot more readable (and understandable for me) doing it that way, instead of the \d

Comment: @Chris Schmich: Yes the original expression doesn't match all the strings that my regular expression does... and this is why it doesn't work. :) If you carefully look at his example you can see it doesn't fit the pattern that his regular expression is looking for.

Comment: @Mark Byers: But now you're also matching strings that I don't think the original regex ever *intended* to match.  It just seems like the original regex needed tweaking to support optional negative values, i.e. `@"(X-?(?:\d*\.)?\d+)*(Y-?(?:\d*\.)?\d+)"` which supports the two examples in the question and still rejects other cases that I think should probably still be rejected (see my example above).  In other words, I could propose a regex of `X.*?Y.*?`, which would fix his problem but also introduce lots of new ones.

Comment: @Mark Byers: I based mine off of the original regex which has more issues than just handling the negative.  I think gbacon's answer below is the most accurate.  Basically, it's `content = Regex.Replace(content, @"(X-?(\d+\.\d+|\d+\.|\.\d+|\d+))(Y-?(\d+\.\d+|\d+\.|\.\d+|\d+))", "$0G54");`.  It's more verbose, but it covers everything well and rejects the rest.

Answer (score 1):

To be picky about the input, you could use

```
string num = @"-?(?:\d+\.\d+|\d+\.|\.\d+|\d+)";
content = Regex.Replace(content, "(?<x>X" + num + ")(?<y>Y" + num + ")", "${x}${y}G54");
```

Is there a reliable terminator for the Y value? Say it's whitespace:

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"(X.+?)(Y.+?)(\s)", "$1$2G54$3");
```

How robust does the code need to be? If it's rewriting debugging output or some other quick-and-dirty task, keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

What comes after "X(value)Y(value)" in your text file? A space? A newline? Another "X(value)Y(value)" value pair?

I'm not very good using shortcuts in regexes, like \d, nor am I familiar with .NET, but I had used the following regex to match the value pair:

```
(X[0-9.-]+Y[0-9.-]+)
```

And the replacement is

```
$1G54
```

This will work as long as a value pair is not directly followed by a digit, period or a dash.

Comment: I for one am a huge fan of the `[0-9]` syntax over `\d`. It's far more readable and with regular expressions, ANYTHING that enhances readability is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question directly, but you should check out [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm). It's a .NET Regular Expression Tool that allows you to debug, test, and fine-tune your complex expressions. It's a life-saver.

More of a do-it yourself answer, but it'll be helpful even if someone gives you an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to support optional negative values:

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"(X-?(?:\d*\.)?\d+)*(Y-?(?:\d*\.)?\d+)", "$1$2G54");
```

Comment: When run on my test case this gives output `"foo X17.8Y-1G54. bar"`.

Comment: @Mark Byers: see my comment on your answer, but yes, mine is incorrect.  I based it off of the original regex and just added support for negatives.  There were other issues with the original regex.  gbacon's answer is the most accurate.