# Find / Replace, Exclude Character

Tags: regex, notepad++

Similar to [Find and Replace RegEx question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806789/find-and-replace-regex-question)

All I need to do is find a string between two phrases, "literal" and "edited [;", and replace with the same string, omitting all "//". I don't think parenthetical backreferences are what I want because the text file I'm working with is huge and there are typically 3, sometimes up to 10 "//" in each string.

This:

```
// --- Literal
//
//At the same time as that, joining in the music
//will be fun, I think.
// --- Edited
```

should become this:

```
// --- Literal

At the same time as that, joining in the music
will be fun, I think.
// --- Edited
```

(Notepad++ does not support newline characters in its regex but that is unrelated to the issue. In the actual text I've done a find-replace for \n to be "nline".)

This is what I have so far:

```
Find:    // --- Literalnline//(.*?)//(.*?)//(.*?)//(.*?)// --- Edited // \[;
Replace: // --- Literalnline\1\2\3\4// --- Edited // \[;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would not want to do this with regex, but I gave it a go anyway: http://regex101.com/r/tF6bZ1

`/\A(\/\/ --- Literal)[\r\n]+|(\/\/ --- Edited)\z|\/\/(.*[\r\n]*)/gi`

This does not do any validation of any sort or whatever, just matches straight up and down. You should be able to replace with `\1\3\2` or such.

Good luck!